# How to get SharePoint pages and page content using POSTMAN or Graph Explorer?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, postman, sharepoint-online

I will need all pages and page contents that are created under the libraries of the SharePoint site using POSTMAN or Graph Explorer.

Can anyone help me with the same?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoints doesn't have pages, hence I assumed you are preferring to sites and site content.

Based on this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/list?view=graph-rest-1.0), you can retrieve SharePoint [sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) contents using the `GET sites/{site-id}` and `GET /lists/{list-id}` endpoints respectively.

To access the root SharePoint site within a tenant use `GET sites/root`.

As the question was a bit general, this documentation [Get the document library for a site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using `GET /sites/{siteId}/drive` endpoint may also be helpful.